# In the code below, i need to know how to start my data in column B4, and also how to use a certain row(say row c) for my x axis data

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have some code below that was written for me by someone else.  I am making a line chart for each row in a sheet, and placing those charts on sheet 2.  I just need to modify this code so that I can start my line chart data from cell B4, all the way to the end of that row where data is available.  I also need to have row 2 starting with cell C2, be my x axis data, which is dates that are listed out through row 2.

[image]

```
Sub main()
   'variable declaration
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim Sht As Worksheet



    'Find the last used row
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A54").End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last used column
    LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        Set Sht = ActiveSheet
    'Looping from second row till last row which has the data
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        'Sheet 2 is selected bcoz charts will be inserted here
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        'Adds chart to the sheet
        Set chrt = Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        'sets the chart type
        chrt.ChartType = xlLine

        'now the line chart is added...setting its data source here
        With Sht
            chrt.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, LastColumn))
        End With

        'Left & top are used to adjust the position of chart on sheet
        chrt.ChartArea.Left = 1
        chrt.ChartArea.Top = (i - 2) * chrt.ChartArea.Height

        Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work for what you requested.

```
Sub main()
'variable declaration
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim Sht As Worksheet



'Find the last used row
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B54").End(xlUp).Row

'Find the last used column
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("C2").End(xlToRight).Column
    Set Sht = ActiveSheet
'Looping from second row till last row which has the data
For i = 4 To LastRow
    'Sheet 2 is selected bcoz charts will be inserted here
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    'Adds chart to the sheet
    Set chrt = Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    'sets the chart type
    chrt.ChartType = xlLine

    'now the line chart is added...setting its data source here
    With Sht
        chrt.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, LastColumn))
    End With

    'Left & top are used to adjust the position of chart on sheet
    chrt.ChartArea.Left = 1
    chrt.ChartArea.Top = (i - 2) * chrt.ChartArea.Height

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When I tried that, it sent me to sheet 2, but nothing copied over to sheet to.  Thank you for your response I really appreciate it!  Do you have any idea why its doing that?

Comment: It is working for me. What I see happening though is that during the last part where the code is adjusting the chart location, it moves the chart to row 29 (and off the screen on sheet two.). Try stepping through the code and you will see it happen.

Comment: Ah yeah you are right, I do have one chart, but I need a chart for each row of data.  In the original code, if I delete the first 2 rows and first column, the code creates charts for each row.  What I am trying to get away from is having to delete those unneeded rows and columns.  When I do delete the rows and columns, my first chart starts in the top left corner of the sheet 2 and the rest are lined up directly underneath that one

Comment: The code I provided will produce for each line. It is based on the same format of data you have in your screenshot.  I see what the issue is with placing the first graph in the upper left hand corner of Sheet2 (cell A1). The code you have sets the Chart Top at 0. I would recommend changing the line `chrt.ChartArea.Top = (i-2) * chrt.ChartArea.Height` to `chrt.ChartArea.Top = (i - 4) * chrt.ChartArea.Height`. I think that will do the trick. It is not the cleanest way to position charts but it will suffice.

Comment: Im not sure why, but I cant get it to work on my spreadsheet.  I cant figure out what the deal is